# Can we change user from Chatter External to Chatter Free

Tags: chatter

Can we change the user licence type from Chatter External to Chatter Free and profile from Chatter External User to Chatter Free User. I accidentally created Chatter External for Chatter Free and I need it to change to chatter free user.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to change the license of a user in Salesforce. (But you are able to select a different profile, which uses the same license.)

I suggest to rename the old chatter users to user.name@company.com **.old** and create new users.

(Post etc. can be migrated..)

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your comment  Ugesh.
You are able to deactivate these old users in order to free up and reallocate the licenses. Therefore the licenses aren't wasted. ;-)

Comment: But one licence is waste :(